# Which is better to use for referencing single cells in excel: A1 or A:A / 1:1?

Tags: excel

Is there a difference when using a cell reference and column / row reference when pointing to a single cell? Or is there a better way? Sample table below.

I have been using column / row reference for faster checking of formulas, using Show Formulas, but I do not know if it has an impact to memory and processing times for very large files.

Sample table (A/B or C/D?):

```
R\C  A        B        C        D
1    25       18       13       21
2    14       19       22       17
4    =A1+A2   =B1+B2   =1:1+2:2 =1:1+2:2
6    =A4      =B4      =4:4     =4:4
```

Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you test this very easily yourself to see if there's any difference? And can't you very easily try reading to see which one is easiest to understand? What will make more sense to you 6 months from now when you come back to make a change?

Comment: Whatever you type is going to be parsed by Excel into an internal format that you have no direct access to. If they have equivalent meanings and the programmers who wrote the Excel formula parser are competent, it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @Ken at several thousand values and given the computer I'm using, I don't see much of a difference. I already have a preferred style as stated, but the data grows and I have to share files and so I was wondering if there is a logic to how excel treats these.